# LaTeX - Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a diagram like this one?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You could use `pgfplots` could you provide a minimal working example of what you've achieved so far?

Comment: Or plain TikZ. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick sketch but this is the basic idea using `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \begin{document}    
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel={Zeit},%
        ylabel={Produktivität},%
        xmin=0,%
        ytick=\empty,%
        xtick=\empty,%
        no markers,%
        smooth,%
        axis lines=left]
    \addplot{(-x^2+x*4)};
    \addplot{0};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Which would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Add `axis lines=left,no markers`, and it's even closer.

Comment: You can even add `smooth` to get smoother lines

Answer (score 3):

This example of [`PGFPlots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf)should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        title=My title,
        ylabel = Produktivitet,
        xlabel = Zeit,
]
\addplot[
   red,
   domain=0:20,
   samples=17,
]
{-x^2+12*x};
\legend{X}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]